# how do you avoid "meta.xml" files from being deleted during a merge

Tags: apex, deployment, git

i find that the working of git removes the meta.xml of the apex classes. Here is what i have,

`dev` branch with `2 feature branches`. And in the dev branch, there were 2 `apex` classes.So the files in the dev initially was --> E.g. **`user1.cls user1.cls-meta.xml & user2.cls user2.cls-meta.xml`**

Worked on `feature1` branch, and merged to `dev`. Now `dev` have say, `user1.cls and user1.cls-meta.xml` (i have deleted all the other files user2.cls files which is not the part of `feature1`)

Then i make changes to the other 2 classes on the `feature2` branch, 1 is to modify an existing class (`user2.cls`) and add a new class, `user3.cls`. while merging `feature2` into `dev` , i have the below files left in the `dev` branch

```
user1.cls  --> intact 
user1.cls-meta.xml --> lost in the merge
user2.cls   --> modified class on feature2 branch (intact)
user2.cls-meta.xml --> lost in the merge
user3.cls   --> is the new class added (intact)
user3.cls-meta.xml --> intact
```

So, i lost the meta.xml of user1 and user2 classes. 
i think this is the right way of git but how do you guys solve this issue in salesforce development

---

Reason why this is right way in Git is because:
* while starting dev branch have all the 4 files for the user1 and user2 class files. 
    user1.cls
    user1.cls-meta.xml 
    user2.cls
    user2.cls-meta.xml

- created `feature1` and `feature2` from `dev`
- on `feature1` branch, i modified only the `user1.cls` file and deleted the files belonging to `user2.cls`. i left the `user1.cls-meta.xml` but it wasn't modified as a part of `feature1`.
- merged `feature1` to `dev`, due to this merge dev one now have what `feature1` branch have.
- on `feature2` branch, i modified `user2.cls` and added the `user3.cls and user3.cls-meta.xml`
- Merged `feature2` to `dev`, now this is where things are happening. git thinks that the `user1.cls-meta.xml` was removed from `feature2`, so it removed it. it didn't removed the `user1.cls` file as it was a modified version from what feature2 had. On the feature2 branch: `user2.cls-meta.xml` was not modified even though `user2.cls` was modified. And the same file was removed from dev, so git merge think it should be removed as well.
- Finally it keeps the new `user3.cls and user3.cls-meta.xml` in the `dev` after the merge as these are new files

I think i can checkout the file manually prior to the merge, but this will be a tedious process if the number of files is more.

Comment: git does not do any automatic removal of -meta.xml files. Are you by chance not committing them? If not, you probably should.

Comment: @ca_peterson updated the question to be more precise